# Dynamic folder name in dynamicWrite FileIO in data-flow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow, apache-beam-io

I have a `PCollection<KV<String,String>>`. I want to group data by K and write all values for a Key K into  file(s) on google storage inside a folder named K.   Suppose I have 2 entries after using by to group the values.

```
['a',[apple,as]],['b','bat,ball']
```

I want to write all the file by name data_record.txt inside folder-name 'a' for 'apple,as' and 'b' for 'bat,ball'.
How can I create dynamic folder names using `FileIO.dynamicWrite`? The folder must be named by the key used to group.